# C# Parse JSON to Dictionary<string, List<string>

Tags: c#, json

I have some JSON returned inthe format of :

```
[{
"Strains":[{
    "Description":"String content"
    }],
"Description":"String content"
}]
```

Where there is a one to many relationship between the Description and the Strains.  I want to parse this into a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, could somebody please advise what I should be looking at to achieve this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I've tried deserializing as such:

```
JsonDeserializer des = new JsonDeserializer();
var foo = (List<Dictionary<string, object>>)des.DeserializeObject(json);
```

However, no joy.  I'm just having a play with JSON.net, to see if there's anything there that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's failing because technically it's not a straight cast to a `Dictionary<string, object>`. The "Strains" property is an object, whilst the "Description" property could be mapped as a `KeyValuePair`

You'll need to deserialize this to an object. Have you tried [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)?